# Mean fo a geometric using Conditional expection

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, means

I am trying to understand the derivation of the mean of a geometric distribution from the example in Bertsekas' "INTRO. TO PROB.".

[image]

He uses conditional expecations, $$E(x|A_i)$$ to find the $$E(x)$$

I don't undersand the above argument. Are they using any independece/memorylessness concept? If I know that the first n tries are failures. then the remaining tries follow still follow the same geometric distribution?

$$ E[x|x>n] = n + E[x] $$

Comment: If you view the geometric distribution as "number of independent Bernoulli trials until one success", then it follows from the independence of the trials.

Comment: A good example to think of would be number of flips of a coin to obtain a Head $(H)$. Let $X$ be the number of flips until a Head appears and $p$ be the probability of $H$ in each flip.

Comment: Then $E(X) = 1 + (1-p) E(X)$. $p$ is the probability that the first flip is $H$ and $(1-p)$ is the probability that the first flip is not $H$. Outcome of the subsequent flips are independent of the outcome of the first flip and that is why $(1-p) E(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are using memorylessness property, though the exact proof can be checked as follows;

$$ \mathbb E(X|X>1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X > k |X > 1) =2+ \sum_{k=2}^\infty \mathbb P(X > k |X > 1) = 2+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \mathbb P(X > k-1).$$
Doing the change of variables, $k-1= u$:

$$ \mathbb E(X|X>1) = 2+\sum_{u=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X > u) = 2+\sum_{u=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X > u) - \mathbb P(X\geq 0) = 1 + \mathbb E(X).$$

Where i used the fact that $\mathbb P(X \geq 0) =1$ and $\mathbb E(X) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb P(X>n)$ for a non-negative random variable.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you please explain how $$ E(X|X > 1)$$ equals  sum to infinity of probabilties? Doesn't geometric distribution start from k=1 ?

Comment: Check 5 in the following link: https://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Properties2.html